# Как пропорционально увеличить матрицу?

Tags: алгоритм

Имеется матрица следующего вида:

```
|0 0 1 0 0 |
|0 1 1 1 0 |
|0 0 1 0 0 |
```

Как её пропорционально растягивать? Например увеличить в 10 раз?

Comment: Что значит «увеличить матрицу»? Какой конкретно результат вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: `Что значит «увеличить матрицу»?` - Нужно сравнить 2 массива, предварительно подогнав под один масштаб. Массив представляет собой фигуру из 2D координат (x,y) "вырезанных" с изображения. `Какой конкретно результат вы хотите получить в итоге?` - процент соответствия одного массива - другому.

Comment: Покажите на примере, что будет при увеличении матрицы `[[0 0][[0 1]]` в два раза. А то мнения разные могут быть...

Comment: `при увеличении матрицы [[0 0][[0 1]]` - это тут не уместно. Одна матрица известна. Вторую нужно привести к масштабу первой, чтоб их можно было корректно сравнить.

Comment: Уместно. Будет в результате один единичный пиксел? Четыре? Один единичный и три со значением 0.5?

Comment: А что значит "увеличить в 10 раз"?  Если в заданной матрице 3 * 5 всего 15 элементов, сколько должно получиться в результате - 10 * 15 ? Или каждое измерение увеличивается в 10 раз?

Comment: Я в очередной раз убеждаюсь, что ru.stackoverflow - для дебилов. Я пришёл с простым вопросом, а мне кучу встречных вопросов. Как в Израиле... Всё, что выходит за пределы понимания - плохо, либо противоречит чьим-то интересам... Почему закрыли вопрос [Как распознать объект по его геометрии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1470737/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8) а эту тему заминусовали?

Comment: - Скоро на ru.stackoverflow будут вопросы, типа "сколько будет 2+2?" и не более, или как нарисовать сайт в конструкторе сайтов, а всё остальное - коммерческая тайна. С бюджета 60 млн. на автопилот автобусов, +Tesla автопилот и тема "машинного зрения" - табу. Аналогичная ситуация и с другими вопросами: Если тема имеет хоть какой-то коммерческий интерес - она закрывается... Или как вариант - набегают троли и "делают мозг".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, есть ли в `Numpy` готовый метод (наверняка есть, но я такого не помню), но если "вручную" сделать, то всё просто:

- создаём новую матрицу нужного размера
- проходим по её ячейкам и кладём в них элементы из исходной матрицы с координатами, полученными из координат в новой матрице путём деления на коэффициент "раздувания" матрицы

Для примера я взял увеличение в 2 раза, чтобы можно было нормально получающуюся матрицу напечатать:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(
    [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
k = 2
new_arr = np.zeros((arr.shape[0]*k, arr.shape[1]*k), arr.dtype)
for i in range(new_arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(new_arr.shape[1]):
        new_arr[i,j] = arr[i//k,j//k]
new_arr
```

Вывод:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Получается, нужно умножить каждую ячейку в ряду на коэффициент увеличения? Если `К=3` то вывод в первой строке, будет 8 нулей 3 единицы и ещё 8 нулей. Правильно? Или 12 нулей?

Comment: 2*3 = 6, а не 8 же.